# BiDiMode of Delphi StringGrid change after impression

Tags: delphi

I want to print a `StringGrid` which has `BiDiMode` set to `bdRightToLeft`.

The Grid works fine until I start a preview of impression, when the `BiDiMode` changes to `bdLeftToRight` and my data are reversed.

I am under Delphi 3.0 and I am using `TMSadvStringGrid` and `AdvGridPrintSettingsDialog`.

How can I change grid direction in the printout?

Here is a describing picture:
[image]

Comment: "*until I start a preview of impression*" - what does that mean? "*I am under Delphi 3.0*" - are you really using a 22-year-old IDE/compiler, or is that a typo?

Comment: Perhaps there is an issue with your code. [mcve] please.

Comment: That form does not have a Delphi 3.0 icon, so you're clearly not using Delphi 3. You should contact TMS for support for their controls, which is free for licensed users. We don't have their source code to see what their print preview code is doing, and we don't have yours to see what you're doing either.

Comment: I am using Rad Studio 10.2.3, and i want to fill the grid with arabic language wich mean that i must use bdRightToLeft BidiMode alsow i am using TMS advanced StringGrid  and AdvGridPrintSettingsDialog (v 9.2.4.0) to print easily the grid      procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if not AdvGridPrintSettingsDialog1.Execute then exit;
end;     heer the priview show that the grid orientation is bdLeftToRight my probleme is that i am unable to print the grid as it is presented at app runtime

Comment: *RAD Studio 10.2.3* is not *Delphi 3.0*.